# How do I display and analyse the contents of a .pcap file using python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pcap, tcpdump

I have an [Edyn Garden Sensor](https://edyn.com/), which is a device that measures light, temperature, humidity and soil water content & soil nutrients. It connects to my wifi network every 10min for a few seconds, and transmits this data to some server on the web. Then, I can use a mobile phone app to see these measurements (although the display of the data is not exact, i.e. no numbers). Since I'm an ecologist, I want to use this device for more than that, but I don't know how to get the data. Hence my question. I want to intercept the connection going out to the server and use it for statistics.

What I have done so far: I've made a Raspberry Pi into a Wifi Router, and the only device I've connected to it is the [Edyn](https://edyn.com/). Then, I dumped its communication ran  into a .pcap file using

```
tcpdump -i wlan0 -w edyn.pcap
```

The content of *edyn.pcap* is one connection, transmission and disconnection, i.e. I ran tcpdump for 10min.

Now, how do I find out what's in *edyn.pcap* and interpret it using python, so that I can display the measured data? And is there a way of getting a constantly updated readout every time the Edyn connects to the Raspberry Pi (I'd like to save data to .csv)?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: To start, open the pcap file in Wireshark running on a windows, Mac, or Linux machine. You'll be most interested in the payload portion of the tcp/ip packet. You need to understand that first.  If it's encrypted, you're pretty much screwed

Answer (score 0):

There's a pcap http python parser here
https://github.com/xiaxiaocao/pcap-parser 
Other parser also exist (dpkt), but beware that the traffic may be encrypted.

Hope it helps